# Question about Compact operator and Compactness

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Suppose we have a finite measure space $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ and an integral operator $T: L^p(X)\to L^q(X)$. We also assume that this operator is compact that is for every bounded sequence $\{f_n\}$ in $L^p(X)$ the sequence $\{Tf_n\}$ has a convergent subsequence in $L^q(X).$ Suppose I am saying that for a bounded set $B$ then image set $T(B)$ is compact. So now I am confused about how these two are related. I mean does the compactness of the operator $T$ implies that the compactness of the set $T(B)$ or vice versa? Like suppose my operator T is compact and using the compactness of the operator T if I prove that $T(B)$ is compact then are these two different results or the same results? Please if someone clears this doubt.

Comment: The image set won't necessarily be compact, but its closure will be compact.

Comment: so that means if my operator is compact then if I prove that for any set $B$ the set $T(B)$ is compact then these two will be different. Also while proving $T(B)$ is compact I am using the compactness of the operator $T$.

Comment: Here is a proof of the equivalence between "For all bounded sets $B$, $T(B)$ is relatively compact" and "For all bounded sequences $(f_n)_n$, $(T(f_n))_n$ admits a convergent subsequence", which are thus two equivalent definitions of a compact operator, just to clarify my comment: [A linear operator is compact if and only if the image of any bounded set is relatively compact](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3051274)

Comment: I don't know if you can have that the image of *every* bounded set is compact, I feel like there might be complications, but that would indeed be stronger than just having your operator be compact.

Comment: Actually, I have assumed that the space $X$ is a compact (As particular case to apply the Arzela-Ascoli theorem). Then I proved that for bounded set $B$, $T(B)$ is equicontinuous and uniformly bounded so by Arzela-Ascoli theorem I concluded that $T(B)$ will be compact.

Comment: Arzela-Ascoli requires $T(B)$ to be known to be closed before applying the theorem to have $T(B)$ be compact at the end, otherwise you only get that $T(B)$ is relatively compact!

Comment: so for that purpose only I assumed $X$ as a compact.

Comment: Edited my last comment, hope it's clearer.

Comment: okay got your point. Suppose if I modify my $B$ as a closed subset instead of a bounded subset. So since $T$ is linear then $T(B)$ will also be closed. Will this modification work?

Comment: You don't really need to modify anything, Arzela-Ascoli works for all sets, it's just that the conclusion is having relative compactness instead of straight-up compactness.

Comment: Yes but the relative compactness is already established when I proved that $T$ is compact operator. Now I was thinking to show for any bounded subset $B$, $T(B)$ is compact but as you said we need closeness of $T$ so I assume $B$ as closed subset and since I have already have the boundedness and equicontinuity of $T$ then I can conclude that $T(B)$ is compact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a counterexample to the claim that there exists a nonzero operator which could satisfy the property that the image of every bounded set is compact and not just relatively compact:

Let $T : X \to Y$ be a nonzero operator between two normed spaces $X$ and $Y$. Assume by contradiction that every bounded set has closed image.
Because $T$ is nonzero, there exists $x \in X \setminus \{0\}$ such that $T(x) \neq 0$.
Now simply let $x_n := \frac{1}{n} x$. By assumption, the bounded set $B := \{x_n \mid n \in \mathbb{N^*}\}$ ($\mathbb{N}^*$ means the positive integers without zero) has compact image through $T$, hence the set $C := \{T(x_n) \mid n \in \mathbb{N^*}\} = \left\{\frac{1}{n} T(x) \mid n \in \mathbb{N^*}\right\}$ is closed.
However, $\frac{1}{n}T(x)$ converges to $0$ when $n$ tends to $\infty$, meaning that $0$ would belong to $C$, but none of the vectors in $C$ are the vector $0$ since $T(x) \neq 0$, absurd.

Hence every nonzero operator admits at least one (but it's actually an infinity of course) bounded set of non-closed image. Since compact sets are in particular complete and thus closed, your operator cannot have send all bounded sets on compact sets.

What I mentioned in my comments still holds though, that is an equivalent definition of compact operator is that every bounded set is sent on a *relatively compact* set, aka a st of compact closure. See here for example: [A linear operator is compact if and only if the image of any bounded set is relatively compact](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3051274/1104384).